# Taking Partial Derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Given $$x^3 + y^3 = 3xcy$$ ( Folia of Descartes )take $dy/dx.$

So doesn't that mean $y' = dy/dx$

and that its partial is $x^3 + 3y^2 y' = 3xc ?$

The solution is given as:

$$3x^2 + 3y^2y' = 3cy + 3cxy'$$

I dont't get what I'm missing. I'm rusty at this so I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Here, $y=f(x)$. So,

$$\begin{align}
x^3+y^3&=3xcy,\\
\frac d{dx}\left(x^3+y^3\right)&=\frac d{dx}\left(3xcy\right),\\
3x^2+3y^2y'&=3cy+3xcy'.
\end{align}$$

This is because $d/dx(x)=1$ and $d/dx(y)=y'$.

Answer (score 1):

To differentiate $cxy$, use the Constant Rule and the Product Rule. The derivative of $cxy$ with respect to $x$ is 
$$c\left(x\frac{dy}{dx}+y\frac{dx}{dx}\right)=c\left(x\frac{dy}{dx}+y\right).$$

**Remark:** We are not finding partial derivatives. We are finding the ordinary derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$, using [*implicit differentiation*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation)